# Disable IE 9 Addon on IE startup, w/Powershell and then Enable on IE exit

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, browser-addons

I know we can disable all addons/exts when we start IE using the "-extoff" switch. But is it possible to disable a single IE addon from a shortcut start or through a script? And then re-enable the addon/ext? Problem I have is that we use a web application and it uses an addon, but we have a few computers that have another addon/ext they want to keep enabled but they both interfere with each other at times. They are not used at the same time.

Basically,

- Script that will Disable a single specific Addon in IE.

  ... run IE ... exit IE ...
- Script that will Enable that single specific Addon in IE.

**EDIT1:**

I created a powershell Script:

```
$regpath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Settings\{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}"
if(!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $regpath))
  {
   echo "NOPE. RegPath is not there!"
  }
else
  {
   echo "RegPath is there! Lets change it..."
   Set-ItemProperty -Path $regpath -Name Flags -Value 0
   # Note: 0 is for enable and 1 is for disable.

   #start IE and then wait until its finished and then set addon back on
   echo "Starting IE..."
   C:\Progra~1\Intern~1\iexplore.exe | out-null
   echo "IE Exited. "
   Set-ItemProperty -Path $regpath -Name Flags -Value 1
  }
```

This script worked fine on my workstation, the registry item was changed... but IE still had the addon running when it started. So what am I missing? I tried a SLEEP on IE startup, nope. Am I setting the reg item in the wrong place? Why isnt IE seeing the registry change? If I manually change the registry item IE will see the change, but not when I use powershell. Do I have to update the registry before starting IE? Save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question.

1. This example Powershell Script disables the "Adobe PDF Link Helper" extension in IE v9.
2. Starts IE, and then waits until it closes....
3. Then re-enables the same extension.

You can start IE without the Powershell script, the extension will be on. Use the script to disable a specific extension and run IE.

You need the "Class ID" of the extension and modify the registry to that specific extension.

- Name:                   Adobe PDF Link Helper
- Publisher:              Adobe Systems, Incorporated
- Type:                   Browser Helper Object
- Architecture:           32-bit
- Version:                9.5.5.316
- File date:              ‎Wednesday, ‎May ‎08, ‎2013, ‏‎5:58 AM
- Date last accessed:     ‎Today, ‎March ‎15, ‎2014, ‏‎5:34 PM
- Class ID:               **{18DF081C-E8AD-4283-A596-FA578C2EBDC3}**
- Use count:              252
- Block count:            104
- File:                   AcroIEHelperShim.dll
- Folder:                 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX

[image]

**Powershell Code:**

```
# Adobe PDF Link Helper Registry Path (with CLASS ID)
$RegPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Settings\{18DF081C-E8AD-4283-A596-FA578C2EBDC3}"
if(test-path $RegPAth)
{
    #CD $RegPath
    Set-Location $regpath
    echo "Disabling IE Ext... and Starting IE...will wait."
    Set-Itemproperty . Flags -Value 1

    Start-Process "$env:ProgramFiles\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -wait # -ArgumentList -extoff

    echo "IE Done... will Enable Ext now..."

    Set-Itemproperty . Flags -Value 400
    echo "Enabled IE Ext."
}
```

**NOTE:**
Setting the "Value" to 1 will "**disable**" the extension:

```
Set-Itemproperty . Flags -Value 1
```

Setting the "Value" to 0 should "**enable**" the extension, but I had weird results when setting the value to 1:

```
Set-Itemproperty . Flags -Value 0
```

Setting the "Value" to 400 will "**enable**" this extension, but this might be a value that the Adobe Extension uses and might be different for another extension. I have seen 40, 580 as values for "Flags" DWORD.

```
Set-Itemproperty . Flags -Value 400
```